# How do I create student report cards in Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, ms-access, report

a noob here looking for some help.

So I work at a school and results are going to be sent out to parents soon. I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

[image: See this]

I am looking to create report cards for all students that looks something like this:

[image: See this]

How do I achieve this in Microsoft Access?

To start with I created a table that contains all the students' data of the school(name, ID, etc...) and then I imported the excel sheet shown above into Access.

I have imported the excel sheet into Access and it looks something like this:
[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wivuc.jpg)

What do I do next?

P.S. Sorry for the long post. Thanks for any help you can provide. Much appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm not an expert in Access but you probably want to look at Access Reports
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-simple-report-408e92a8-11a4-418d-a378-7f1d99c25304
Might help

Comment: Perhaps you need to spend a solid week studying an introductory Access tutorial book to get an understanding of basics on relational database principles, Access functionality, programming concepts, VBA and/or macro coding. The Excel worksheet does not have data in normalized structure and column headings are repeated. Really could not have imported data that way. Unless you normalized data, getting that report output will be difficult.

Comment: @June7 unfortunately I have time till 19th May to submit it. I don't think I have enough time to do that :( Do you think you would be able to recommend any such book to me please?

Comment: @June7 I've just attached an image to my original post of how I imported the excel sheet into Access. Can you please take a look? Thanks!

Comment: That data is not normalized. However, can arrange fields on report vertically as you show in image and that might meet your needs. No, I don't have any specific book to recommend.